# How to use lambdas to use std::function with member functions?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, std-function, stdbind

I'm trying to move some global functions inside a class. The current code looks like this:

```cpp
struct S{};

void f(S* s, int x, double d){}
void g(S* s, int x, double d){}
/*
...
...*/
void z(S* s, int x, double d){}

int main()
{
    function<void(S*, int, double)> fp;
    
    //switch(something)
    //case 1:
        fp = f;
    //case 2:
        fp = g;
    //case n:
        fp = z;
}
```

Suppose I wanted to update the code above to something like (this code bellow doesn't compile):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    void f(int x, double d){}
    void g(int x, double d){}
    /*
    ...
    ...*/
    void z(int x, double d){}    

    void method_that_has_some_logic_to_use_the_others_above(int x, double d)
    {
        function<void(int, double)> fp; // How do I have to declare here?
        //switch(something)
        //case 1:
        fp = f; // How can achieve something like this using lambdas here?
    //case 2:
        fp = g;
    //case n:
        fp = z;

        fp(x, d);
    }

};


int main()
{
    S s;
    s.method_that_has_some_logic_to_use_the_others_above(10, 5.0);
}
```

I've seen some solutions using std::bind but read somewhere to avoid using it and prefer lambdas. I'm using C++17, but I have little experience with lambdas and wasn't able to figure out how to solve it with the examples I've found in other answers.

Comment: Do you need a `std::function` instead of a pointer? (Maybe, but your example is simple enough that a function pointer could be used in the first scenario, and a pointer-to-member-function in the second.)

Comment: I'm trying to update a few parts of the code and it is currently using `std::function`, ... I've updated the example to show approximately how its being used in the real code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member functions require a specific class object to invoke, so you need to do

```
function<void(S*, int, double)> fp = &S::f; 
fp(this, x, d);
```

Or use lambda to capture a specific class object and invoke its member function internally

```
function<void(int, double)> fp = [this](int x, double d) { this->f(x, d); };
fp(x, d);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EYbz41Esn)

Answer (score 1):

***Note:** I'm presenting an alternative approach because the OP could not justify the use of `std::function` (and because an answer to the literal question has already been given by 康桓瑋).*

---

As long as you are just choosing between member functions *with the same signature* to invoke, a `std::function` is has unnecessary overhead. The overhead is probably not critical, and you do have more flexibility if you need to expand beyond a simple member function call. On the other hand, a pointer-to-member-function provides similar functionality without the overhead.

The downside (for me) is the syntax. The type in this case is `void (S::*)(int, double)`, which is hard to read if you're not used to pointers-to-member. On top of that, the variable being declared goes in the middle of the type, which again hurts readability. Still, if you can accept the syntax:

```cpp
// Placeholder for the decision-making process:
char choose_fun() { return 'g'; }

// Same setup for `S` as in the question, except with the following added:
void S::other_method(int x, double d)
{
    void (S::* fp)(int, double);  // Manual type specification
    // decltype(&S::other_method) fp;  // Possibly easier to read

    switch (choose_fun()) {
        case 'f': fp = &S::f; break;
        case 'g': fp = &S::g; break;
        // ...
    }

    // More processing?

    // The syntax for invoking a pointer-to-member is also a bit weird.
    (this->*fp)(x, d);
}
```

---

Actually, if the setup really is as simple as presented in the question (a simple `switch` to decide what to call), I probably wouldn't bother with either pointers or `std::function` in this setup. I would store the value used by the `switch`, then call the functions via a helper function. (If there is no additional processing, then `other_method` simplifies to the helper function.)

```cpp
// The helper function.
void S::choose_method(char choice, int x, double d)
{
    switch (choice) {
        // Returning void is legal and takes the place of having a `break`.
        case 'f': return f(x, d);
        case 'g': return g(x, d);
        // ...
    }
}

// Now the other method needs very little code in addition to the additional
// processing, whatever that is. This also brings the code closer to the
// ideal of one task per function.
void S::other_method(int x, double d)
{
    char choice = choose_fun();

    // More processing
        
    choose_method(choice, x, d);
}
```